# htaccess & routing problem in Code Igniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to get this right, but there is always one part that doesnt work, so i would be so grateful if someone could help me out.

What im trying to achieve in htaccess is:
To remove trailing slashes, and enforce www.

So these 4 examples need to show the same result:

```
#1. www.mysite.com/products/show/
#2. www.mysite.com/products/show
#3. mysite.com/products/show/
#4. mysite.com/products/show
```

They all need to show #2, as that is the correct on.

There are a lot of examples and solutions out there, to do this, and i get it to work, BUT! im also using a route on this controller, looking like this:
$route['products/(:any)'] = "products/show/$1";

Once again, it is all working, both the htaccess and the route, the problem arises when (:any) contains a slash, example foo-bar. Then suddenly #3 fails and the site just doesnt load at all and for some weird reason the url changes to www.domain.tld/products/foo-bar (yes, it actually prints out domain.tld, im not using it as an example. and that domain is of course not even a valid domain.)

Below is what i currently have in my htaccess, please do keep in mind that for the enforce of www, i can not! hard code the actual domain name, because there will be more than one domain pointing to this document root, all using the same script im building.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /



#RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|doc)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Grateful for any help,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

WWW Problem: Perhaps you need a CNAME record for mysite.com to point to www.mysite.com? That's my best guess with the given information.

URI Routing: Keep in mind, that when (:any) in /products/(:any) contains a slash, the route is no longer /products/(any).. it is /products/(any)/(something_else).  This is handled as another segment to your URL.

You won't be able to use something in your URL with a slash in it if the slash is not part of your routing. You could do some kind of encoding/decoding if you just need that passed in the URL.

As to why it's routing to domain.tld, I have no idea. :)

Comment: thanks for your reply drewjoh, i will ask my host and see if they can sort that out for me.   Still looking for a htaccess solution as well though.

Comment: Updated my answer for you.  Hope it helps a little.

Comment: thanks, i have now removed the routing and am using __remap instead, and still the same problem is there. Am just sending a request to my host to have a look and perhaps add the cname. thanks for your help!